# Java Interface to Force .equals() Override

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have an interface for a factory. Assume an interface for `Module` exists (I need to differentiate between module subtypes). Any two factories defined by the same leaf class of the inheritance tree are always identical.

```
public interface ModuleFactory<T extends Module> {
    T createModule(long seed);
}
```

These factories are going into a `Set` and so their being identical is determined by `.equals()`. Therefore, I need a way to enforce that implementing classes override this method. The set will fill with duplicates otherwise.

The issue is that `Object` already implements this method, so any concrete class will already have an implementation of the method. I cannot simply put `boolean equals(Object obj);` in my interface, as any concrete class will already satisfy the interface with the default implementation. How can I force an override?

Comment: You can't.  There's nothing in the language that will let you.

Comment: Wait, I thought I had searched for a duplicate but one slipped through my fingers. Apologies for the duplicate question.

Comment: I *think* you can force an override if you use an abstract class (declare `equals` as abstract) but there might be reasons why you can't use an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force an equals override.  But you can create an abstract class, provide an implementation for `equals()` which would essentially call an customEquals() method, which is abstract.  So, all your classes are forced to implement the `customEquals()`; where you can provide the custom implementation for `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

try used the code below:

```
  public abstract class ModuleFactory<T extends Module> {

        public abstract T createModule(long seed);
        private int _hash = -1;
        // You yourself generate the HashCode on create instance class
        public OnChangeStatusListener(int _hash) { 
            this._hash = _hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            ModuleFactory that = (ModuleFactory) o;
            return _hash == that._hash;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return _hash;
        }

    }
```